# CooCox CoIDE and FreeRTOS compilation

Tags: freertos, coocox

I use CooCox CoIDE 1.7.4 in order to programm the STM32F051R8 microcontroler, at windows 7 Home OS.  I am a begginer at this kind of programming. My first target is to make some leds blink by using FreeRTOS. After spending many hours trying to do it, I saw some tutorials and many links at web but i couldn't find something helpfull. The compiler was complaining all time presenting this:

*GCC HOME: C:\CooCox\CoIDE\gcc\GNU Tools ARM Embedded\4.7 2013q2\bin
compile:
    [mkdir] Skipping C:\CooCox\CoIDE\workspace\test1\test1\Debug\bin because it already exists.
    [mkdir] Skipping C:\CooCox\CoIDE\workspace\test1\test1\Debug\obj because it already exists.

**BUILD FAILED
Output filename conflict: port.o would be produced from C:\CooCox\CoIDE\workspace\test1\FreeRTOSV7.5.2\FreeRTOS\Source\portable\Softune\MB91460\port.c and port.c
Total time: 1 second***

If someone can help I would kindly appreciate that. If someone need more info please reply. I don't know what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that you have 2 'port.c' files in the project - first in the mentioned freertos dir, second in project root. Try renaming one of them to "port1.c"

Comment: Also, if a project for STM32 is referencing a project for 16FX architecture (on Softune, a different compiler), there may be further confusion about.

Comment: it looks like you have 2 versions of port.c: